# Trying to create curl in excel vba

Tags: vba, api, winhttprequest, mollie

I'm trying to create a paylink with mollie in excel via api

When I just use curl, below is working:

```
curl -X POST https://api.mollie.com/v2/payments \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
   -d "amount[currency]=EUR" \
   -d "amount[value]=10.00" \
   -d "description=Order #12345" \
   -d "redirectUrl=https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/" \
```

In VBA I wrote

```
Sub paylink()
Dim Payload As String

Payload = "amount[currency]='EUR'&amount[value]=10.00&description=Order12345&redirectUrl=https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/"


TargetURL = "https://api.mollie.com/v2/"
Set httpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
httpReq.Open "post", TargetURL, False
httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer test_XXXXXXXXXX"
httpReq.PostText Payload
httpReg.Send
httpReq.WaitForResponse
Debug.Print (httpReq.ResponseText)
End Sub
```

This result is

```
{"status":404,"title":"Not Found","detail":"Invalid resource endpoint","_links":{"documentation":{"href":"https://docs.mollie.com/guides/handling-errors","type":"text/html"}}}
```

What do i do wrong?
Thanks JMP URL was indeed wrong/ I edited the code a little more to get it working

```
Sub paylink()
Dim Payload As String
Payload = "amount[currency]=EUR&amount[value]=10.00&description=Order12345&redirectUrl=https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/"


TargetURL = "https://api.mollie.com/v2/payments"
Set httpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
httpReq.Open "post", TargetURL, False
httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
httpReq.Send Payload
httpReq.WaitForResponse
Debug.Print (httpReq.ResponseText)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Your URL's don't match up.

Comment: Thanks. I was so focusses on the httprequest i didn't see the wrong URL.